# Why mongodb logs commands in the log file and how to avoid that?

Tags: mongodb, logging

**OS: Windows 10/ Server 2012**

**Mongodb verison : 3.4.9**

I have set the mongod --logPath and --quiet command line parameter

The logs are just growing beyond 100mb and not rotating. Seeing the logs I see lot of entries example:

> I COMMAND  [conn9] command DBNAME.VERSIONS command: find {

How can I restrict mongodb to log these as I really do not care about the command

Comment: @Stennie, Sherry mentioned in the question that --quiet parameter is used when starting the mongod. Still the operations slower than 100ms are logged in log file?

Comment: (reposting my comment which was slightly mangled): How long are these commands taking to run (i.e. the timing at the end of the log line)? All commands slower than the [`--slowms` threshold](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-slowms). What does the timing at the end of the log line look like? Slow commands (default: 100ms) will be logged. You could increase this threshold if you have a high tolerance for slow queries or don't want to see them logged.

Comment: @Mani The [`--quiet` parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod-quiet) limits some diagnostic output like connection accepted/closed events and replication activity, but slow commands have a separate threshold. Normally admins would want to have slow commands/queries logged for investigation. Anoher option to limit logging would be to [configure log rotation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/), which is managed outside of the MongoDB server. For example, using `logrotate` on Linux to send a signal to rotate the logs.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So commands are taking more than 100ms, for examle 
"I COMMAND  [conn63] command admin.$cmd command: listDatabases" is about 120ms

Which makes me think why these are taking so long?

Also another entry which is showing up too much are
 "I NETWORK  [conn28] received client metadata from"

How can I stop these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase the slowms value , follow the below steps:

For Exmple, If you want to increase the slowms vlaue to 500ms

```
db.setProfilingLevel(1, 500)
```

It will set the slowms to 500ms and will also turn on the profiling. So to stop the profiling, run the below command.

```
db.setProfilingLevel(0)
```

This can also be done by restarting MongoDB with the `--slowms` option.

*Now, the commands will get logged in the log file only when the command takes more than 500ms to execute.*